# 'Like' operator in field validation rule not working for OLEDB inserts

Tags: c#, validation, ms-access, operators, oledb

First of all, I'm no programmer, I'm doing this for fun for a small project at work (I'm team lead in customer service).

I created an Access database with the following validation rule: Like "T######"
in order to only accepts our employee IDs (e.g. T123456)
It works fine in Access.

However, in C#, I have the following code on my submit button:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "insert into Employees (ID, LastName, FirstName) values ('" + txtTID.Text + "','" + txtLastName.Text + "','" + txtFirstName.Text + "')";

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
            connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Whenever I enter something like the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kng34.png) above, I get an [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV051.png) saying it couldn't insert the data because of validation rule.

I tried with a different wildcard (*) and it still doesn't work. Is there anything obvious I'm missing here?

Thank you so much for the help, have yourselves a great day!

Comment: Can you include the error message?

Comment: You code is at risk of [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). You should use prepared queries with parameters. Even if you are doing it just for fun it can be useful because it gracefully handles the case where the name contains a `'`.

Comment: @developer_117 error message added :) thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: where in your code are you using the `LIKE` keyword and sql wild card such as `%` `%`

Comment: @MethodMan Sorry if I wasn't clear, the validation rule is in Access directly and not in the code.

Comment: well perhaps you should edit the question and show that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit upon a limitation of the Access OLEDB provider. Your code should work as expected if you switch to using `System.Data.Odbc` and the Access ODBC driver.

Comment: Worked perfectly with ODBC, thank you!
I used https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/standard-security/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I couldn't write you a comment. There is a validation rule on your table. This means the problem is not your query but in your table architect. for example it could be, the data you are trying to insert doesn't match the data type of your fields
see [this for more info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restrict-data-input-by-using-validation-rules-b91c6b15-bcd3-42c1-90bf-e3a0272e988d)